# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection when creating a feed with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

I'm experiencing the following error when trying to put together a feed of posts based on the different user id's the user is following.

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.query.EP.path')

I'm using redux & firebase/firestore and the error occurs in the following action at line

> const uid = snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[1];

```js
export function fetchUsersFollowingPosts(uid) {
    return ((dispatch, getState) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(uid)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .orderBy("creation", "asc")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                const uid = snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[1];
                const user = getState().usersState.users.find(el => el.uid === uid);
                let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data, user }
                })

                for(let i = 0; i< posts.length; i++){
                    dispatch(fetchUsersFollowingLikes(uid, posts[i].id))
                }
                dispatch({ type: USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts, uid })

            })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, you are doing simcoder instagram clone project
well thanks to [henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67212258/14078264) to provide your solution and finally i got the answer for the problem follow these steps to solve the problem

just replace this

```
dispatch(fetchUserFollowingPosts(user.id))
```

to this

```
dispatch(fetchUserFollowingPosts(user.uid))
```

just replace it to `user.uid`

and the replace this

```
const uid = snapshot. query.EP.path.segments[1]
```

to this

```
const uid = snapshot.docs[0].ref.path.split('/')[1]
```

its work for  [codenanshu](https://codenanshu.in)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, before the error line, just put **console.log(snapshot);**
After that, I inspect the element and found out my query is [My query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aurW.png),
So my case is **const uid = snapshot._delegate.query._query.path.segments[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aurW.png)**;
Maybe everyone will get a different path, so better to check out yourself in inspect element in developer tools console.

Answer (score 0):

You're also doing the simcoder insta thing?

I just replaced this:

```
dispatch(fetchUserFollowingPosts(user.id))
```

with:

```
dispatch(fetchUserFollowingPosts(user.uid))
```

just replace it to `user.uid`

Answer (score -1):

While implementing the instagram replica practice app by SimCoder, I also came across the section in code where we needed to extract the specific uid for each query by using

```js
const uid = snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[1]
```

I however found that unnecessary, as closure in javascipt binds inner functions to outer functions lexical scope, ensuring they have access to parent function variables.
Hence, referencing the uid variable means that we will always get the correct reference. Please [read more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), I am open to corrections if I am getting it wrong, thanks.